# Problem with saving bson data using JPA Hibernate from Spring Boot application into Informix database

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc, informix, bson

I'm having a problem saving bson data using java pojo object with help of JPA annotation. Tried a lot of different types on entity field which is mapping bson column from informix(running in docker developer latest - *14.10.FC3DE*) database.
Closest to solution is to use custom JPA `@Converter` on field

```
@Convert(converter = BsonConverter.class) 
private IfxBSONObject values;
```

but error that I get is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown object type
SQL Error: -79728, SQLState: IX000
```

If I use directly `IfmxPreparedStatement` and `setIfxBSONObject` together with jdbc connection then data is imported to database, but then I'm loosing niceness and abstraction from Spring Boot JpaRepository's and JPA.

After some debug I think problem is in informix jdbc(version 4.50.3) drivers `IfxPreparedStatement` class on line

```
val = IfxValue.makeInstance(this.jconn, x, (IfxColumnInfo)null, targetSqlType);
```

where `IfxColumnInfo` is not supplied, which later in selection process use of `IfxColumnInfo` and `extendedId`(or `extendedName`) could be used to select bson object.

I think solution for bson columns should work also with JPA entity fields with types `String`, `BSONObject` or `Map<String,Object>`.

Exception stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown object type
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildExceptionWithMessage(IfxErrMsg.java:416)
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:397)
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:379)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.createInstanceFromClassName(IfxValue.java:378)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.makeInstanceFromIfxType(IfxValue.java:573)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.makeInstanceFromIfxType(IfxValue.java:557)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.makeInstance(IfxValue.java:537)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.makeInstance(IfxValue.java:504)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.setObject(IfxPreparedStatement.java:1865)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.SqlTypeDescriptorRegistry$ObjectSqlTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(SqlTypeDescriptorRegistry.java:162)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$1.bind(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:88)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2929)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3226)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3760)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:443)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3202)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.save(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.save(Unknown Source)
at org.homesensors.measurement.RestAdapter.getTestData(RestAdapter.java:56)
at org.homesensors.measurement.RestAdapter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$87f03bcb.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
at org.homesensors.measurement.RestAdapter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f90426d.getTestData(<generated>)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

If this method `static String getIfxTypeName(IfxConnection conn, IfxColumnInfo colinfo)` in `IfxValue` class was called, then it will have chance to select at least `if (colinfo.ExtendedId == 26) {className = "IfxBSONObject";ifxtype = 44;}`

Also, one more question, what this method is used for `private static String getClassNameForExtendedId(int id)` in `IfxValue` class?

Comment: Can you post the method call stack for that version of the JDBC driver?  There are several routes that can lead you to a -79728. I'm curious what JPA passes and calls into the Informix JDBC driver to lead to that exception.  Sounds like something that could/should be fixed. Or if there is a simple reproduction project I can try to run and investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the stack. Sorry to ask one more thing. Do you know the sqltype value that hibernate passed into the setObject() method?  What happens is that we call into these makeInstance methods and end up calling IfxTypes.FromJDBCToIfxType(sqltype) and what we get back is probably UNKNOWN which later throws the Unknown object type exception.  This class is a bit messy :(

That method (getClassNameForExtendedId) is not used, and I believe is removed and replaced in the upcoming release.

Comment: `targetSqlType=1981449756` in `setObject` method. `IfxTypes.FromJDBCToIfxType(sqltype)` method returns 49. Last effort it looks in `IfxTypeToObjectTable_9x`, and then comes exception. This is for IfxBSONObject, I think it is necessary to have support for little more neutral object type for bson/json on JPA entity field.

Comment: IFX_TYPE_UNKNOWN is what that 49 is.  Certainly this can be made better. I've put in to get this fixed. Note if hibernate could pass in Types.JAVA_OBJECT which is 2000 as the targetSqlType the JDBC driver works here. Not sure if you can get Hibernate to do that.

Comment: I did not work much before with hibernate, more with eclipselink, therefore I do not know is it possible to set that type in hibernate properties. My goal was to escape to work on jdbc level :-), and do not think some much about connections, preperad statemants, etc... :)Tired of that in past.